# Extra brackets in output Using Scala

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and was going through the basic commands. Following are my doubts:

1) On using println and calling a function in the statement it prints an extra "()" in the output. Can anyone tell me why is it so. Below is my Code and output

My Code --

```
{
private var name : String = s_name
private var grade : String = s_grade
private var marks : Int = s_marks

def getStudent(){
var str = printf("Name :: %s Grade :: %s ",name,grade)
println(str + marks(marks))
println("Alphabets in your Name :: " +name.length())

}

def marks(marks: Int) : String = {
return "Marks :: " + marks
}
}
```

Using this to call the above piece of code:

```
var student1 = new Student("Zahid Ansari","A", 55)
student1.getStudent()
```

Output --

```
Name :: Zahid Ansari Grade :: A ()Marks :: 55
Alphabets in your Name :: 12
```

Why does it print "()" in output.

2) if I change the marks method as below :

```
def marks(marks: Int){
print("Marks :: " + marks)
}
```

and call it as:

```
println("Name :: " + name + " Grade :: " + grade + " " + marks(marks))
```

Output comes as :

```
Marks :: 55Name :: Zahid Ansari Grade :: A ()
Alphabets in your Name :: 12
```

Why is the Marks method executed before the first part of print statement.

Comment: I suggest going through some tutorials on programming in general and Scala in particular.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var str = printf("Name :: %s Grade :: %s ",name,grade)
```

prints out `Name :: Zahid Ansari Grade :: A` and puts the return value of `printf` into `str`. A return value of `printf` is `Unit` (i.e. "nothing"), and it gets printed by

```
println(str + marks(marks))
```

as `()`.

Try to insert `println("=====")` after `var str = printf...` line -- you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The output as per your suggestion is  ============
Name :: Zahid Ansari Grade :: A 
()Marks :: 55

Comment: No, it's not. Pay attention, please. You've inserted println("=====") *before*, not after printf line.

Answer (score 0):

Let's split output of 'getStudent' method code line by line

```
def getStudent(){ 
var str = printf("Name :: %s Grade :: %s ",name,grade) //line1
println(str + marks(marks))     //line2
println("Alphabets in your Name :: " +name.length()) //line3
}
```

Line 1 : is printing 'Name :: Zahid Ansari Grade :: A' and also assigning a unit value to var str which is '()'
Line 2 : When you are printing str + marks(marks) it is printing '()Marks :: 55' 
Remember on this line () is getting printed due to var str holds unit value. 
It doesn't actually hold string that you are forming on line 1.

In scala you can write line 1 as 
    **println(s"Name :: ${name} Grade :: ${grade}")**